# Why can't I have more than one drop shadow angle in Photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I have two images in separate layers. I want one to have a drop shadow at 6°. I want the other to have its degree set to 100.

When I change one layer style, it changes the other.

How can I have more than one direction of drop shadow? It's really irritating me! I tried rasterizing the layer but it won't let me.

Answer (score 2):

In the layer's Blending Options, set the drop shadow angle of your first layer, and make sure to uncheck "Use Global Light"

[image]

Now, for your other layer, repeat, and also uncheck "Use Global Light". The result will be two different angles for your drop shadows:

[image]

Global lighting is useful if you don't want to set individual shadows or change all at once, but in your case you want the opposite.